# Word VBA 'find red text' stops if whole paragraph is red

Tags: vba, find, ms-word

I have a macro that jumps to the next occurrence of red text in a document.

It works fine until it gets to a paragraph that is all red (including the paragraph mark). It then won't move forward in the document until I move the cursor forward and try again.

I've also noticed that when the cursor is within the paragraph, if I run the macro, only the text from the cursor to the end of the paragraph is highlighted.
I suspect I need to use some form of 'collapse'? Can anyone advise?

Here's the code:

```
Sub Find_Red_Text()
With ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow
    .ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code finds the next occurrence of red text. You have accurately described that action. But you also seem to want from it that it should select a broader range of red text if the selection is already red (meaning, no search is required), and you seem to wish that it should continue searching the next red range when you run it again. These two requirements are conflicting in themselves, but your code doesn't provide for either of them.

Comment: @Variatus - thanks again for your help. I've added collapse statements and it now seems to be doing what I want.